# Migrating .NET 4.0 application and deploying in Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

Currently our .NET 4.0 application is deployed in Windows Server 2008 R2. We are planning to upgrade our Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016. Will our application run in latest .NET framework or we need to upgrade our application's .NET framework version to higher version if we deploy our application in Windows Server 2016?

Comment: Did you test it? Ultimately what anybody says on here doesn't matter. You need to deploy your app and test it to verify all the dependencies are in place.

Comment: Microsoft made no promise that it will "run in latest .NET Framework". Any upgrade can hit breaking changes, so that's why you need lots of efforts.

Comment: @mason, We are planning to use either Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2016. We need to give estimation effort to client. That is why I asked the question without testing.

Comment: So you're planning to give an estimate to your clients based on what some random people on Stack Overflow told you instead of testing it yourself? That's silly. .NET Framework will not be your applications only dependency, there will be others. If you want to give a proper estimate, you *must* test. And you shouldn't be deploying a new Windows Server 2012 box in 2020. Why would you deploy something that's already obsolete?

Comment: It's impossible for us to know whether your app will run in a specific .NET version without seeing the application itself. Also, FWIW I'd recommend you go ahead and upgrade to 2019 instead of upgrading to a server OS that's already 4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this move from  Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016 and **it did not** need to upgrade any web application. They run just fine.

Some issues that you may have are:

- As years pass by, you always make small changes on IIS, add some MIME types, change some permissions... change some ISAPI filters - stuff like that may show you some errors at first.
- New Permissions on the servers web site directory and on the databases.
- Maybe some extra ISAPI filter that is not run anymore on the new IIS

Comment: What is the version of the .NET Framework that your app was built on?

Comment: @RGS There are many web sites of different versions of 4 and up

Answer (score 1):

.net 4 is .net 4 and as long as the new servers have the same target version of the .4 framework then you no code changes will need to be made. For example, 4.6.2 runs on both Windows 2008 r2 and Windows 2016 and there is no upgrade involved here.

You will need to do full regression testing to ensure that the configuration of the server itself is correct and any dependencies are present and correct.